# frequency of words in a file

Tags: java, file

I was wondering if someone could explain why I get an error with List in the getSordsInOrderOfFrequency method

```
 public List<String> getWordsInOrderOfFrequency(){ 
    List tmp = new ArrayList<String> (frequencies.keySet());
    Collections.sort (tmp, this);
    return tmp;
```

here is my parse method and frequencies for reference:

```
 public Parser() {
    // do not change the constructor, this initializes an empty Map
    frequencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}



public void parse (String filename) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String word = scanner.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]"," ").toLowerCase();
        if(!frequencies.containsKey(word)){
            frequencies.put(word, 1);
        }
        else{
            frequencies.put(word, frequencies.get(word)+1);
        }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you explain how you need help or what is it that you currently don't understand?

Comment: as it stands this is not a question - StackOverflow is a question and answer site not a help site.

Comment: As @LeleDumbo points out below, you are creating a local variable in the parse method that hides the class member variable of the same name - this means you are populating the local var, not the class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you are sorting the list based on the word, not the frequency.

Create a node class `WordFrequency` to store the word and its frequency, and make it implement `Comparable<WordFrequency>` :

```
class WordFrequency implements Comparable<WordFrequency> {
    private final String word;
    private final int frequency;

    public Word(final String word, final int frequency) {
        this.word = word;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public int compare(final WordFrequency other) {
        if(other == null) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(frequency, other.frequency);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, iterate through your map creating a list of WordFrequency objects and sort the list.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring issues related to comparison, you have overriden `frequencies` in the `parse` method. Thus, the method uses the local variable instead of instance one. Therefore, calling `getWordsInOrderOfFrequency` after `parse` will result in empty list.